# EIdSocketError in release mode

Tags: delphi, exception, delphi-xe2, webrequest, indy

I'm maintaining a **SOAP** Server (with a **TWebModule** containing **THTTPSoapDispatcher**, **THTTPSoapPascalInvoker** and **TWSDLHTMLPublish**) in **delphi-XE2** and i can't find a way to handle an **EIDSocketError** ( not in debug mode !).

I'm not even sure where it's raised from... I know that it's raised after a user disconnects while waiting for a response from the server (request timeout or network lost on client side).

It's certainly raised by the **IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge** component, so I tried to handle it from `myIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.OnException` without success. I read here and there that it where raised but avoidable in debug mode, but can't find a clue on how to handle it in release mode or even prevent it from from being raised...

i can provide code on requested part of my application if needed.

```
MyService.exe

program MyService;
{$APPTYPE GUI}


{$R 'documents.res' 'documents.rc'}

uses
  Forms,
  Sysutils,
  WebReq,
  IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge,
  UFMyService in 'Unit\UFMyService.pas' {FMyService},
  UWMMyService in 'Unit\UWMMyService.pas' {WMMyService: TWebModule},
  UDMMyService in 'Unit\UDMMyService.pas' {DMMyService: TDataModule},
  UIMyService in 'Unit\UIMyService.pas',
  UCMyService in 'Unit\UCMyService.pas',
  superobject in 'Unit\superobject.pas',
  superxmlparser in 'Unit\superxmlparser.pas',


{$R *.res}
const
  se = '/';
begin
  if WebRequestHandler <> nil then
    WebRequestHandler.WebModuleClass := WebModuleClass;
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.Title := 'My Service';
  try
    Application.CreateForm(TFMyService, FMyService);
    Application.Run;
  Except on E:Exception do
    begin
      Log('!! Exception au lancement : '+E.Message);
      Application.Terminate;
    end;
  end;
end.
```

then in

```
UFMyService.pas

unit UFMyService;

interface

uses (...)

type
  TFMyService = class(TForm)
    ApplicationEvents1: TApplicationEvents;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ApplicationEvents1Exception(Sender: TObject; E: Exception);
(...)
  private
    FServer: TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge;
    procedure handleException(AContext: TIdContext; AException: Exception);
(...)
  end;

var
  FMyService: TFMyService;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  UWMMyService, UDMMyService, (...);

procedure TFMyService.ApplicationEvents1Exception(Sender: TObject; E: Exception);
begin
  if not(E is EIdConnClosedGracefully) and not (E is EIdConnClosedGracefully) then
  begin
    Log(e.Message);
  end;
end;

procedure TFMyService.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  (...)
  FServer := TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.Create(Self);
  FServer.OnException := handleException;
  (...)
end;

procedure TFMyService.handleException(AContext: TIdContext; AException: Exception);
begin
  if not(AException is EIdSilentException) and not(AException is EIdConnClosedGracefully) then
  begin
    Log(AException.Message);
  end;
end;
```

`[edit]`

'Back from ages.

It turns out that it's delphi and its TWebRequestHandler that's displaying the popup :

```
procedure TWebRequestHandler.HandleException(Sender: TObject);
var
  Handled: Boolean;
  Intf: IWebExceptionHandler;
begin
  Handled := False;
  if ExceptObject is Exception and
    Supports(Sender, IWebExceptionHandler, Intf) then
    try
      Intf.HandleException(Exception(ExceptObject), Handled);
    except
      Handled := True;
      System.SysUtils.ShowException(ExceptObject, ExceptAddr);
    end;
  if (not Handled) then
    System.SysUtils.ShowException(ExceptObject, ExceptAddr);
end;
```

i just don't know how to handle the exception myself...

if i declare the OnException of my WebModule, i can log the exception but no matter how i try to handle / Release it, it's still displaying the popup :

```
procedure TWMMyService.WebModuleException(Sender: TObject; E: Exception;
  var Handled: Boolean);
var
  AnError : TObject;
begin
  Log('!! WebModule Error ('+Sender.ClassName+')');
  Log('!! Type : '+E.ClassName);
  Log('!! Message : '+E.Message);
  Handled:=True;
// later add-on
  if( E is EIdSilentException) then
  begin
    //Socket 10054 Connection reset by peer.
    //etc...
    AnError := AcquireExceptionObject;
    if (AnError <> nil) then
    begin
      Log('!! Ignore Exception');
      ReleaseExceptionObject;
    end;
  end; // then the popup appears...
end;
```

`Log('!! Ignore Exception');` is reached, but ReleaseExceptionObject has no effect; maybe too late.

i changed WebRequestHandler.MaxConnections to 100 to prevent clients from beeing stunt too fast by those socket exceptions, but imagine having to validate 100 popup to keep on working... i just can't leave it this way ^^

Thanks all for any suggestion/advice/solution :)

`[edit]`

Still trying to find a solution months later, nobody knows ? i get tired of this Delphi intrusive and tiring bug, 'cause it can be nothing less than that !

Comment: code is extremely heavy, wich part must i provide ?

Comment: Don't free the exception on handleExceptio() or in OnException. It will be freed by exception handler that calls OnException.

Comment: thanks, i remove this part (but in fact i can't even log the error, so i don't enter at all the OnError event function...)

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to handle the exception at all?  `EIdSocketError` means a socket error occured.  Chances are that the connection was either lost or closed incorrectly. Indy server-side connections are multithreaded.  A socket error means the socket is likely in an unstable state and needs to be closed.  Letting Indy handle the exception internally will stop the connection's owning thread and close the socket for you.

Comment: how can i do that since indy raises the error itself and display immediately a pop-up window that stunt the application after 10 -or so- popup shown ?? If i could prevent it from displaying pop-ups, it could be no harm... anyway, Thanks for reading me ^^

Comment: sorry, the application is not stunt, but it can't accept more connections

Comment: if there are no more cases, then i must be pointing number 2... where do i have to search for those "default exception handlers" ?

Comment: #2 is not likely given the multithreaded nature of Indy's servers, unless you are synchronizing with the main thread in your code, or your main thread code is accessing client connections directly. You will just have to run your project in the debugger to see where the exception is actually being raised from and what the call stack leading up to the exception looks like.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the popup message?

Comment: ---------
Erreur d'application
---------
Exception EIdConnClosedGracefully dans le module MyService.exe en 0015F334.

La connexion s'est fermée proprement.

(connection has been closed successfully)

Comment: I have no socketerror to grab immediately, but as soon as i can make it happen willingly, i'll post it ^^

Comment: Application error. 
Exception EIdSocketError in module MyService.exe at 00153D40. 
Socket Error # 10053. 
Software caused connection abort.

Comment: That is not what I meant by "screenshot". I wanted you to take an actual onscreen screenhot image of the popup message and then attach it here. But whatever. If you are seeing the exception inside the debugger, then the debugger can show you exactly where the exception is coming from, like I said earlier. If the exception is occuring inside of a worker thread and not in the main thread, then you can safely ignore it, and you *SHOULD NOT* be seeing a popup message at runtime when running the app outside of the debugger.

Comment: "you SHOULD NOT be seeing a pop-up message at runtime when running the app outside of the debugger" and that's why I'm here, i do receive those pop-ups while outside of the debugger ^^'

Comment: There are only 2 ways that can happen, as I already outlined earlier - an uncaught exception is being raised inside the main thread, or a worker thread is explicitally catcing the exception and displaying its own popup message for it (which it should not be doing under normal situations).  Indy-based servers do not do either one of those.  So again, I strongly suggest you run your app inside the debugger and see where it tells you the original exception is actually coming from, then you can track down who is displaying the popup message for it.